# How to create full viewport screen website layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, viewport

I am just starting with both media queries and viewport statements. Is this what is used to create websites like the following ?

http://html5up.net/escape-velocity/

http://www.sitediscount.ru/parallaxer3bs/index.htm

What I am trying to achieve is a full page / viewport on all screen sizes. Then on scroll to the next section below is also filled with the viewing area. This is a new popular type web desin and I am trying to figure out how to replicate it. Either html5 or bootstrap solutions would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes, media-queries is the main way to go in order to create fluid layouts.

If you're just starting out, I would recommend you to learn writing these from scratch in order to get an understanding. There is a good article available at http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

However, if you do not wish to code the media-queries yourself; that kind of pages with a fluid responsive layout can easily be made with bootstrap.

To download bootstrap, go to http://getbootstrap.com and start working from there.